# Command-Tab to X11.app in Mac OS X 10.6 doesn't focus X apps

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, xorg

If I have an application open in X11.app on Mac OS 10.6 and I switch away to another app and then back with <kbd>Command-Tab</kbd>, none of the X application come to the foreground.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/)
2. Bind a hotkey to Execute AppleScript: `tell application "X11" to activate`

Good enough.

Comment: [Quicksliver](http://qsapp.com/) may be a workable alternative and is free unlike keyboard maestro.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Command-Tab</kbd> to try to bring X11 to front. While it is in "front" (but not really), <kbd>Command-Tab-Shift-Tab</kbd>, and it will come to front.

In more detail, when it should be in front, <kbd>Command-Tab</kbd> as though you will bring something else to front, but before you let go and activate something else, select X11 again. You can do this by cycling all the way through the open apps, or hitting <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd> while holding down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key.